# Angular2. Add one component to another throught the third

Tags: angular

What I have:

1. `TaskTopPanel` Component. It contains

```html
<sc-dialog #dlg [header]="'Комментарий'" [free]="false" [height]="'500px'" [width]="'550px'"
  [content]="" (opening)="openingListener($event)"
  (closing)="closingListener($event)">
</sc-dialog>
```

2. `DialogComponent` (it is called in `TaskTopPanelComponent`)

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'sc-dialog',
  template: require('./dialog.component.html'),
  directives: [FindPersonDlgComponent],
})
export class DialogComponent {
```

3. Several components  with content

I want to know, is it possible to pass components(or, maybe, only view) to `DialogComponent` , when I call it from `TaskTopPanel` Component?

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible in Angular2 to combine different templates/html into the same page as if it were all one template?

Comment: @jhhoff02  Not exactly, i whant to pass one  template to another thow the third.
In other words, when i call my dialog ,i what to set content of this dialog. and this content is a view of some component.)) 
 
it seems like i can use ViewChild, but i am not sure this is the good way.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody wants to know, i found  solution. It is 
 1. Add element  to compponent, where you want to see your content. in my case: DialogComponent.html looks like:

```
<div class="modal-content grey lighten-3 ">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>.......................ect.....
```

2. Add selector of component, wich you want to add to dialog (in my case ) where you call your component:
TaskTopPanelComponent.html:

```
 <sc-dialog #dlg [header]="'Выбор клиентов'" [free]="false" [height]="'800px'" [width]="'900px'"
                    (opening)="openingListener($event)"
                   (closing)="closingListener($event)"><find-person-dlg></find-person-dlg></sc-dialog>
```